# Writing test cases for OpenCV for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, testing, opencv

I'm using Google's ADT bundle (Eclipse + Android SDK) in conjunction with OpenCV for Android 2.4.6. In order to test a class (no activity) from an Android app, I wrote a test case for it. When I run it, I get this:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_eye:(III)J
at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_eye(Native Method)
at org.opencv.core.Mat.eye(Mat.java:1449)
at de.htw_berlin.threed_scan.utils.SceneStitcher.findTransformations(SceneStitcher.java:71)
at de.htw_berlin.threed_scan.utils.SceneStitcher.consolidateCoordinateSystems(SceneStitcher.java:109)
at de.htw_berlin.threed_scan.utils.SceneStitcher.stitchClouds(SceneStitcher.java:192)
at de.htw_berlin.threed_scan.test.SceneStitcherTest.testStitchClouds(SceneStitcherTest.java:86)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1614)
```

While the project to be tested runs fine, the test project seems to lack the native binarys. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the .so libraries are compiled to the right CPU architecture of the emulator/device you are testing, i.e., if you are running on emulator, make sure the CPU emulator is set to arm (for .so compiled for arm) or intel (x86).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the OpenCV manager to load the library (with `BaseLoaderCallback`) then the library is simply not initialized by the time the tests run through.

There is a special TestRunner for OpenCV you can use. I have only found it in the source code so far, not in the SDK.

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/java/android_test/src/org/opencv/test/OpenCVTestRunner.java

Copy this file into your project and set it as TestRunner in Eclipse.